# Where is "Missing { inserted" coming from?

Tags: xetex, pandoc

I'm using fancyhdr. When I use \fancyhdr{plain}, the output is fine, but when I use \fancyhdr{fancy}, get...

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   C
l.328
```

Here's the section from template...

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\sffamily\raggedright}{}{0pt}{\huge}[\titlerule]
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\LARGE\sffamily\raggedright}{\sectiontitlename\thesection}{16pt}{\LARGE}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\Large\sffamily\raggedright}{\sectiontitlename\thesection}{16pt}{\Large}
\let\MakeUppercase\relax
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

And here's the end of the verbose output...

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/tmp/tex2pdf.21620/input.out) (/tmp/tex2pdf.21620/input.out)
(/tmp/tex2pdf.21620/input.toc)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
[1]
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   C
l.258 \chapter
              {An interview with John Curl}\label{an-interview-with-john-curl}
Output written on /tmp/tex2pdf.21620/input.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on /tmp/tex2pdf.21620/input.log.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   C
l.258 \chapter

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

I'm unable to find any unmatched brackets in my markdown, my template, or any .sty files, and unlike others who see similar errors, I'm not writing any algorithms or formulae.

**Edit:** here's a sample document. Running it give the same results described above, when I switch from "plain" to "fancy."

```
# Hello

darkness, my old friend

## I've

come to talk with you again
```

And here's the pandoc command I'm using...

```
pandoc  --latex-engine=xelatex \
    --template=mag.latex \
    --top-level-division=chapter \
    --toc \
    --toc-depth=2 \
    --verbose \
    -o output.pdf \
    *.md
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete small example document tht allows others to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: I've updated, as requested.